# How to retry a test in xUnit based on specific Exception type

Tags: c#, xunit, xunit.net

I am looking for the way to customize xUnit attribute, possibly, to retry the test on a specific Exception of the test.

Something like

```
[Fact]
[Retry(3, typeof(ArgumentException)]
```

Is there any way to archive this behavior in xUnit?

Comment: Why do you want to retry it?

Comment: Because of unstable environment @Progman

Comment: @user1316502 Have a look at [best practices for writing unit tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-best-practices#stub-static-references). Try to reproduce your unstable environment variables on consistent premises.

Comment: @AlyEl-Haddad this question is not about Unit tests. The area of issue is integration

Comment: "Unstable environment" usually called a "flaky tests" - which should be rewritten to remove it's "instability".

Comment: _I have problem X and want to solve it with Y approach. How I can implement Y?_

Comment: If you honestly believe that a large test suite can avoid flaky tests then you haven't done much testing: https://testing.googleblog.com/2016/05/flaky-tests-at-google-and-how-we.html Google say they have a 1.5% flake rate on good tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at xunit-retry that is, probably, outdated, but was built with same problem in mind.
While it does not support retry on a particular exception, it checks if there were exceptions on line 44 here: https://github.com/giggio/xunit-retry/blob/master/XUnitRetry/RetryTestCase.cs
Calling aggregator.toException will either give you an exception if there's only one or will return AggregateException and then you could check if aggregated exceptions match the list of ones you'd like to retry test

Comment: Some fine fellow has resurrected this one: https://github.com/JoshKeegan/xRetry (life must be pretty dull in Milton Keynes).